# How we can control the internet of our faculty at university?

Tags: networking

I have a problem, in my faculty at university (CS)
we will have our own internet line(30Mb), this is fast compared to the regular internet that provides us the university (really more slow and very restricted). Well, we are approximately 150 ~ 200 students and we need do a management of the network, to avoid downloads or games that could do more slowly the internet. Almost all students wanna do more investigation and learn more, and for do much better the assignments of the courses. I wanna know if there is a possible solution for do this and We really want that it don't will have a high cost(we are in an state college), we have computers for make a network server or some else. Thank you!!

Comment: The typical approach is to restrict direct internet connections and require usage of a [proxy server](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) where you can then set and enforce certain policies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pfSense can do most the things I think you're looking for. It's fairly easy to use without prior experience and provides many of the features you'd find in an enterprise firewall/router.

There are dozens of these firewall/router distributions out there, but it sounds like you're most interested in something that can do QoS or "Traffic Shaping"; adding those keywords to your Google searches might help find what you're looking for.